# Menu is not styled the way I want

Tags: html, css

I have created ul li submenu .If I hover to anchor tag, the sub menu giving space from left side. I dont know what property should I use in css to remove that left side space

Further I want to know how to write for tablet that is responsive only for one device.

My `code`

```
 <div id="nav">
    <ul><li><a href="#">first</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li></ul><!--endofsubmeunu-->
    <ul><li><a href="#">second </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul></li></ul><!--endofsubmeunu-->
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sixth</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">seven</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">eight</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!--endofnav-->
    </div><!--endofwrapper-->
```

`My CSS`:

```
 body
    {

    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    }

    #wrapper
    {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    }

    #nav ul li
    {
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    }
    #nav ul .submenu
    {
    display:none;
    }

    #nav li:hover .submenu
    {
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question could you rephrases it please?

Comment: can you write the responsive css.if you give sample code It is easy to understand for me.after that I can change according to my idea.thank you for your goodness

Answer (score 4):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/vybv5ayv/

Just do follow :

```
#nav li:hover .submenu
{
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if you can guide to write responsive for any device sample code like this I am really very happy to receive because while executing this I got the way to understand.so that I am clear with responsive css

Comment: If worked thn accept my answer! You can use Bootstrap if you have basic CSS knowledge. getbootstrap.com/

Comment: sure I will read these link before I do that I want to know what is the proper way to write responsive way because somebody write in pixel some body write in percentage that's why i am asking because I am not working for any company

Comment: When you use `percentage`, It means that much area of percentage it takes from screen while `pixles` take pixle of screen resolutions. 
Generally, Designer prefers `Pixles` over `Percentage`

Comment: thank you so much,if possible ask some one to write the responsive  sample code  let us  learn both of them, other wise i will write and paste in stack someone like you guide us, like what you did for me.because I always believe stack team and more reliance resource for me

Comment: Yah sure why not ! Accept my answer so It will encourage me more :)
What exactly you want so that I can help you

Comment: once again thank you so much I want know how to write responsive for above code.just for any one device. may be tablet,ios,android.

Comment: thanks boss!you helped me lot..if I have any doubt i will ask after working this,if you also work with this example just post for me i am also working

Comment: Glad It worked for you :) Accept my answer by clicking on right sign of left side. Thanks .